# Adding Dataset in R Package

Tags: r, package, dataset

I want to know the simple and short procedure to add dataset in my own R package. I tried to follow  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bj0gHafa4GE but after that I don't know why data is not appearing in R. As package successfully uploaded in CRAN named as `"DEEVD"`. If I write

```
> data(Rhone)
Warning message:
In data(Rhone) : data set ‘Rhone’ not found
```

I have no idea where I missed the connection because during R-CMD check there is no error and data help files worked perfectly.
Kindly guide me and write in comment section if any further detail is required.
**Edit:**
the answer of @Mossa is very useful But it works correctly in Rstudio. When I updated my Package in CRAN there is same problem. It can be examined after downloading [DEEVD](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=DEEVD)

Comment: If your package code is on github or similar, then we can check if it is setup correctly.
Otherwise, you have to have loaded your package, prior to the `data`-call.
Try this: `data("Rhone", package = YOURPACKAGAENAMEHERE)`.

Comment: @Mossa still there is an issue "Error in data("Rhone", package = DEEVD) : object 'DEEVD' not found'

Comment: Sorry, this `data("Rhone", package = "DEEVD")`.

Comment: same, data("Rhone", package = "DEEVD")
Warning message:
In data("Rhone", package = "DEEVD") : data set ‘Rhone’ not found

Comment: Alright, so send us a link to the repo so I can investigate.. Otherwise, I just cannot help

Comment: you can download that from https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DEEVD/index.html

Comment: From my point of view, everything works exactly as it is supposed to. Maybe you are not deleting the package properly or something. But I cannot see what is wrong. I've downloaded the source from CRAN; I've installed the package from cran, I've removed it.. And every time, the `Rhone`-data is loaded perfectly.

Comment: yes, but it works with 'data("Rhone")' not with 'data(Rhone)'.  Kindly mention why?

Comment: I've looked at the source for `data()` and I cannot figure out what the difference is. Sorry, but you're going to have to suffice with `data("Rhone")` for now :(

Comment: no need of sorry, thankx 4 such help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright, I can finally answer.

The issue is what is written in your `src/Rhone.R` file.
Here you are redefining `Rhone`. That's not what this file is supposed to contain.

Instead this file `src/Rhone.R` is supposed to contain documentation for the dataset `Rhone`.

```r
#' Documentation for `Rhone` should reside here.
#'
#'
"Rhone"
```

Now, here's how I solved it.
First, open the package as a project in Rstudio.
Then (if you don't have it already) install `{usethis}` package via `install.packages("usethis")`.

Then run `usethis::use_data_raw("Rhone")`. You can read the documentation of
this function, to know what it does:

```r
> usethis::use_data_raw("Rhone")
√ Setting active project to 
[REDACTED]
√ Creating 'data-raw/'
√ Adding '^data-raw$' to '.Rbuildignore'
√ Writing 'data-raw/Rhone.R'
* Modify 'data-raw/Rhone.R'
* Finish the data preparation script in 'data-raw/Rhone.R'
* Use `usethis::use_data()` to add prepared data to package
```

Now, go to the `data-raw/Rhone.R` file, and put the definition of `Rhone in there.

At the end, `data-raw/Rhone.R` should look like this:

```r
## code to prepare `Rhone` dataset goes here

Rhone <-
  c(
    1355,
    1492,
    1692,
    1766,
    1903,
    2040,
    2177,
    2314,
    2451,
    2588,
    2725,
    2862,
    2999,
    3136,
    3273,
    3410,
    3547,
    3686,
    3822,
    3959,
    4096,
    4233,
    4370
  )
usethis::use_data(Rhone, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Run/source this script. This now saves a file named `Rhone.rda` to the `data/`-folder.

Now, when you build your package, then this data-file is the only file that is
connected with the name `Rhone`. And not a redefinition of it, as what happened before.

If you change the definition of `Rhone`, then you have to re-run/re-source `data-raw/Rhone.R`. But you only have to do that if you change `Rhone`. And you only can change `Rhone` inside of `data-raw/Rhone.R`. Nowhere else is it possible to change `Rhone`.

If you build and load your package, then the code you used before will work.

```r
> library(DEEVD)
> data(Rhone)
> Rhone
 [1] 1355 1492 1692 1766 1903 2040 2177 2314 2451 2588
[11] 2725 2862 2999 3136 3273 3410 3547 3686 3822 3959
[21] 4096 4233 4370
```

Comment: kindly see my edit.